# How to display favourite posts in user account without using plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I tried wp favourite post plugin but without success, so I insert user meta key in the usermeta table. When user login in his account, after click on posts that id store in user metatable, but I'm not fetch those id.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snippet you tried to use. It would help people answering your question greatly! Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you should try. KK star rating plugin. Link :

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/kk-star-ratings/
```

this will be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow visitors to add favorite posts, you can get a WordPress plugin for favorite posts [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/). Also, it uses cookies for saving data so unregistered users can favorite a post.

Comment: but its not proper working in my site.please give me code logic.so i can apply...

Comment: and what i actually need to how to fetch current login users post id from user meta table..if i get current user login favourite posts ids then i easily get all information....